# How to to update data in DB while doing OneToOne mapping in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, one-to-one

I have a User Class which contain address with OneToOne mapping , when i tried to run it's not inserting data into db(Postgres) and I am not getting any Error also

```
package com.hibernate.sample;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
@Table(name="Siva01")
@Entity
public class UserClass {
   @Id  
   @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
   @Column(name = "UserId") 
   private int id ; 
   @Column(name = "UserName")
   private String userName;
   @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   @JoinColumn(name="AddressId")
   private Address shippingAddress; 


public Address getShippingAddress() {
    return shippingAddress;
}
public void setShippingAddress(Address shippingAddress) {
    this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getUserName() {
    return userName;
}
public void setUserName(String userName) {
    this.userName = userName;
} 
}
```

Address Class :

```
package com.hibernate.sample;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id; 
    private String StreetName;
    private String city;
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getStreetName() {
        return StreetName;
    }
    public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
        StreetName = streetName;
    }
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    } 
}
```

Hibernate.configuration file

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

    <session-factory>

        <!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/hibernateDb</property>
        <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="connection.password">postgres</property>

        <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
        <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

        <!-- SQL dialect -->
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>

        <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

        <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
        <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.internal.NoCacheProvider</property>

        <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>

        <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
        <!-- "create" will recreate entire schema. This is used during initial design when the schemas go through frequent changes -->
        <!--  "update" will update the existing schema -->
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

        <!--  Mapping XML (resource) or annotated class -->

        <mapping class="com.hibernate.sample.UserClass"/>
        <mapping class="com.hibernate.sample.Address"/> 
    </session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

Logs ::

```
Sep 7, 2014 9:39:28 AM org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator initiateService
INFO: HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Sep 7, 2014 9:39:28 AM org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
INFO: HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Sep 7, 2014 9:39:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
Sep 7, 2014 9:39:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
Sep 7, 2014 9:39:28 AM org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate execute
INFO: HHH000396: Updating schema


public class HibernateOne { // Inserts data code 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           UserClass u1 = new UserClass(); 
           //u1.setId(4); 
           u1.setUserName("SaiRam"); 
           Address ad01 = new Address(); 
           ad01.setId(6);
           ad01.setStreetName("PamurRoad");
           ad01.setCity("Bangalore");           
           u1.setShippingAddress(ad01);
           Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
           cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
       SessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.buildSessionFactory(); 
           Session session = sessionFactory.openSession(); 
           Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
           session.persist(u1);
           tx.commit();
           session.close(); 
    } }
```

Please suggest what i went wrong in the above code.

Comment: <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

Comment: Where is your code that inserts data into DB and the corresponding logs generated for that?

Comment: Can you please show the piece of code that for inserting data?

Comment: @Chaitanya - I added the insertion code